# create generic function which can accept any function with its related args for later execution

Tags: go, jobs, goroutine

Is it possible to create a generic function which can accept any other function with its related arguments which can be used later to execute the passed function. I have a requirement where I am planning to first collect all these calls and maintain some metadata of these "jobs" and then execute them later via go routines.

```
// some kind of job function 
func someCoolJob(arg1 type1, arg2 type2) type3 {
    // do processing
    return "value of type3"
}
```

Now is it possible to create a generic function which can take any function with any signature. Previously I have done similar implementation in python, is there some way in go ?

```
func processor(someFunc, relatedArgs){
    // I will save some execution info/ tracking state for someFunc here

    // later I can do something like below in my code
    go someFunc(relatedArgs)
}
```

Is there some better way to organise this in go ? Some other way of implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments through using a [closure](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/25).

Change `processor` to take a function with with no arguments.

```
func processor(fn func()){
    go fn()
}
```

Pass the function and arguments using a closure:

```
processor(func() { someCoolJob(arg1, arg2) })
```